# Plot graph with vertex positioning similar to some other graph

Tags: plot, graph, sage

I'm trying to plot some graphs and it's complementary and I would like the vertices to be in the same place when ploting them. For example, when ploting a cycle graph with 4 vertices:
[image: 4 vertices cycle graph]
I would like to be able to plot it's complementary (edges 1-3 and 0-2) while having the vertices in the same position. Instead, when ploting it's complementary, I get this:
[image: 4 vertices complementary graph]

I tried using a dictionary for the positions but, as I'm ploting multiple ones with *n* number of vertices, this only works for specific cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific use case, I think there is a nice method `.complement()` that preserves this.

```
sage: H = graphs.CycleGraph(6)                        
sage: graphics_array([H.plot(),H.complement().plot()])
```

[image: 6 Cycle graph and its complement]

However, in general you might want to graph another graph on the same locations, and

> using a dictionary

is indeed what you would want to do here.  A simpler example is your first one, but I tweaked the new graph so that it is no longer a complement.

```
sage: G = graphs.CycleGraph(4)
sage: pos_dict = G.get_pos()
sage: pos_dict
{0: (0.0, 1.0), 1: (-1.0, 0.0), 2: (0.0, -1.0), 3: (1.0, 0.0)}
```

This is the dictionary in question, a dictionary of locations.  Now I make the new graph, and try to plot it with the other one.

```
sage: G1 = Graph({1: [3,2], 2: [0]})
sage: graphics_array([G.plot(),G1.plot(pos=pos_dict)])
```

[image: two more graphs]

Comment: that is a better and more flexible solution than mine, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help!  But also glad you showed your chops by solving your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for my *n* vertices problem. This is the code:

```
n = 6

# Don't modify
posi = {}
r = 1

G = Graph()
F = Graph()

for i in [0..(n-1)]:
    for j in [0..(n-1)]:
        if i==(j+1)%n or j==(i+1)%n : 
            G.add_edge( (i ,j) )
F = G.complement()

for i in [0..(n-1)]:
    if n % 2 != 0 and i == 0:
        x=0.5
        y=i
    else:
        if i < n/2:
            x=-0.15 if i%2 !=0 else 0.15 #Avoid consecutive vertices to be in-line
            y=i
        else:
            x=0.85 if i%2 !=0 else 1.15  #Avoid consecutive vertices to be in-line
            y=i-r
            r = r+2
    posi[i] = [x, y]
```

Result (also ploting them together):
[image: G and !G]

While writing this, I figured there are 'cooler' ways to do it but this works perfectly.